# Uncaught Type Error in AJAX success object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typeerror

In the success of one of my AJAX Posts, there's a logical test with the returned "data" object.  Upon the page load, Javascript gives an uncaught type error: cannot read property of undefined on that line:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data[0].ProductID == 1) { //ERROR HERE ON PAGE LOAD, BUT WORKS IN USE
```

The code runs correctly during operation, but yet this error persists upon page load.  I've tried using .val(), .value, and ['ProductID'] to refer to the data point, and also combined it with "&& data[0].ProductID != 'undefined'" and wrapped the entire section in another if to check for undefined "if (data[0].ProductID != 'undefined') {", but the error still appears.  I've tested that the value is never null, and the code works in use, but I'm uncomfortable with just letting it go.  Does anyone have an idea of what's causing this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to test if `typeof data[0] == 'undefined'`

Comment: @jcubic:  That worked, thank you!  If you'll create an answer with that, I'd be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test if `data[0]` is not undefined:

```
if (typeof data[0] != 'undefined' && data[0].ProductID == 1) {

}
```